# Android wrong screen state of screenshot

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, screenshot, android-espresso

I have some steps in UI-test:

```
rotateDevice(Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
closeSoftKeyboard();
assertActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.demo_activity_title));
assertButtonsAreDisplayedInScrollView(mExpectedDisplayedButtonIds);
saveScreenshot();
```

When I run tests, I can see actions on screen, when assertButtonsAreDisplayedInScrollView method starts: display is scrolled to the bottom until the last button, assuring that lowest button is displayed, after that saveScreenshot method is called.

But when I open screenshot.png, I see that it has shotted the initial screen state, i.e. with upper buttons (like it hasn't scrolled to the bottom).

Can someone help to solve this problem? I have to screenshot the last state of screen.

Screenshot method's body:

```
Bitmap bitmap = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().takeScreenshot();

File screenshotFile = getScreenshotFile();

try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(screenshotFile)) {
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
    Log.i(mTag, "Saved screenshot: " + screenshotFile.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(mTag, "Could not save screenshot", e);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a delay in taking Screenshot.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 100ms
        saveScreenshot();
      }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Can happen such thing, that another test will start in 100ms. And screenshot will be taken while another test running. Why exactly 100ms? On some old device tests can work slower and more than 100ms will be needed. And adding explicit wait in tests is not a good practice. I still don't understand why I can see screen in the state after last statement of ui-test, but different state on a screenshot.

Comment: First try checking if you where able to get correct screenshot after adding a delay. Then only you will come to know whether the issue is due to delay or there is someother issue.

Comment: I tried to add delay after assertButtonsAreDisplayedInScrollView and before takeScreenshot. The screenshot was right.

Comment: Before the UI updates you are taking screenshot, so you need to add some few milliseconds delay and then take screenshot. Then only you will get the update view in screenshot.

Comment: Is delay or sleep the only way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes thats the only way because only after the ui updates you need to take screenshot!